# How to rotate a SKNode that has an SKEffectNode child

Tags: ios, rotation, sprite-kit, skeffectnode

I have a `SKNode` that I want to use to organise a number of other `SKSpriteNodes` and `SKEffectNodes`. The ultimate aim is to have a character sprite can change colour of just parts of its body (hence the `SKEffectNode`) plus lots of other behaviours (hence adding them all to a parent `SKNode`)

I want to organise the complex and compound behaviour in an `SKNode` for organisational and learning reasons.

Here's my code:

```
@interface TestNode : SKNode

-(void)rotate;
- (instancetype)initWithPosition:(CGPoint)position;

@end

@implementation TestNode {
    SKSpriteNode *_shape1;
    SKSpriteNode *_shape2;
    CIFilter *_hueFilter;
    SKEffectNode *_effectNode;
}

- (instancetype)initWithPosition:(CGPoint)position;
{

    /* Setup your scene here */
    self.position = position;
    self.name = @"compoundNode";

    _shape1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(80, 30)];
    [self addChild:_shape1];

    _shape2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(20, 50)];

    BOOL useEffectNode = YES;
    if (useEffectNode) {
        _effectNode = [SKEffectNode node];
        [_effectNode addChild:_shape2];

        _hueFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIHueAdjust"];
        [_hueFilter setValue:@0 forKey:@"inputAngle"];
        _effectNode.filter = _hueFilter;
        _effectNode.shouldEnableEffects = YES;
        [self addChild:_effectNode];
    } else {
        [self addChild:_shape2];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) rotate {
    float angle = self.zRotation;
    angle = angle + 0.1;
    [self runAction:[SKAction rotateToAngle:angle duration:0.1]];
    [self updateColor];
}

-(void) updateColor {
    float randVal = RandomRange(0, 6.14);
    [_hueFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:randVal] forKey:@"inputAngle"];
}

@end
```

When this is run and the rotate method called (e.g. from touchesBegan on the scene) the red shape1 rotates as expected but the green shape2 goes a bit crazy. To look at, it seems to be scaled via X then by Y, but no rotation.

[image: Here is the starting image]
Here is the starting image

[image: and after some rotation]
and after some rotation

I've tried logging the zRotation of all the nodes, the parent is updated and all the children remain at 0.0. This is what I expected.

I know I can just change the color of the shape2 node to get around this particular problem, but I still want to understand what's happening for the future.

I know that when I take the `SKEffectNode` out of the equation it all works as expected, so my question is how can I use an `SKEffectNode` in this node tree and have the parent respond to zRotation in a sane manner?

One thought I've had is the issue lies with the `CIFilter` rendering output based on the stored inputImage, which doesn't get rotated, but I'm really guessing now.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. SKSpriteNode contains SKEffectNode that contains another SKSpriteNode.  The SKEffect does not rotate it's geography with the parent. It's child gets squeezed and stretched.

Comment: I reported this as a bug. 17702303

Comment: Great, I still didn't get a resolution to this - I think I just worked round it. Glad it's not just me though :) sorry